# Does someone know an algoritme or solution for a scroll in orthographic camera in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have make an orthographic camera. 1360,2040 big.
I've make a rectangle on a higher position then the y value 2040. That is out of screen. I want that the screen scrolls that I can see the rectangle.  Does someone know the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the [InputProcessor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) interface, or extend the [InputAdapter](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputAdapter.html) (which is a [convenience class](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputadapter)).

In doing this, you have now a *[scrolled](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#scrolled-int-)(int amount)* method that you can override with your behavior code. This method listens to mouse scroll events. The *amount* parameter returns -1 or 1 depending on the direction. So, you will have to increase or decrease the camera position and you're done.

[Here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/15/LibGDX-Tutorial-4-Handling-the-mouse-and-keyboard.aspx), you have an excellent example on how to implement the InputProcessor interface.

Comment: Thanks, but will that also work in android with touch?

Comment: In that case you can override the _touchDragged()_ method

Comment: Thanks, I found another solution for this problem. I use a gesture launcher.